# JasperReportsViewResolver and Spring MVC - Set filename

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jasper-reports

I need help with JasperReports and Spring MVC. I can export everything, but I can't set the filename in the output PDF/Excel that my software exports.

In my dispatcher-servlet I have this bean :

```
<!-- ViewResolver JasperReports -->
<bean id="jasperViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="classpath:/jasper/" />
    <property name="reportDataKey" value="dataSource" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jrxml" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="Report_*" />
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

That is the ViewResolver provided by Spring MVC.
I have a function in my BaseController ( abstract controller extended by all the @Controller ) :

```
protected String exportReport(String reportName, String formatoReport, Model model, JRDataSource dataSource) {
    model.addAttribute("dataSource", dataSource);
    model.addAttribute("format", formatoReport);

    return reportName;
}
```

So, what I do is simply returning this view name from all my @RequestMapping :

```
@RequestMapping(..something)
public String functionName(...something else) {
    .. do some stuff
    return exportReport("Report_docIngresso", EFormatoReport.XLS, model, jrDataSource);
}
```

This works. The export is perfect, but I didn't find the way to set the filename of the exported pdf/excel, that comes out like the latest part of the URL I called before exporting the report.
I already tried to set in the HttpServletResponse the content-disposition with the filename, but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot, 
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Content-Disposition` [HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

```
@RequestMapping(..something)
public String functionName(HttpServletResponse response, ...something else) {
    .. do some stuff

    String header = "inline; filename=myfile.xls";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", header);

    return exportReport("Report_docIngresso", EFormatoReport.XLS, model, jrDataSource);
}
```

(Note I saw just now your concluding comment that you tried without success to set the content disposition header. Well.. I can only say it worked for me in a similar setup.)